# Insert div after last item in every row of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a wrapping ng-repeat set of divs and need to insert a large div under each row but having it be responsive so I can't limit it by using `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-if="($index+1)%3==0"` Maybe using an angular filter to detect number of div's in row and then insert div? Ideally I only want the row to appear when item is clicked. Honestly it basically is an angular version of the Google image layout. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it.

Comment: The `$last` special property will be true when the last item of an `ng-repeat` is being rendered. You could always use `ng-if="$last"` to condition the rendering of your div.